# IF within WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a query with a `IF()` statement within `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, u.user_email, u.user_nicename, u.user_login, u.display_name
    (
        SELECT  b.date_recorded
        FROM    wp_bp_activity as b
        WHERE   b.type IN ( 'activity_comment','activity_update' )
           AND IF(b.type = 'activity_comment', b.item_id, a.id) = a.id
        ORDER BY b.item_id desc
        limit 0,1
    ) as drecord
FROM wp_bp_activity as a
LEFT JOIN wp_users as u ON a.user_id = u.ID
WHERE
   a.type IN ( 'activity_update' )
order by cast(drecord as datetime) desc
limit 0,20
```

But it gives error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT b.date_recorded FROM wp_bp_activity as b WHERE b.' at line 3
```

What's the correct way of using `IF` like that?

Comment: you miss a comma after u.display_name... in first line.

Comment: Could you describe what that `if` statement should accomplish? Because it looks like it could be replaced with a simple statement based on logical operators.

Comment: @guessimtoolate with which statement you mean?

Comment: this one: `... AND IF(b.type = 'activity_comment', b.item_id, a.id) = a.id`. What I mean is that maybe it could that `if` could be replaced with something else (or I'm not getting it).

Comment: @guessimtoolate I meant with which statemant it could be replaced? actually it checks the type if it's `activity_comment` then `b.item_id = a.id` happens and otherwise `a.id = a.id` takes place.

Comment: I meant that the if would be equivalent to: `(b.type = 'activity_comment' && b.item_id = a.id) || (b.type <> 'activity_comment')`. That is if I didn't mess it up. Not sure if that's the solution to your problem, but that if looks weird there -- if b.type is false, then a.id = a.id.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to change is to add comma after `u.display_name`. It should help.

Answer (score 1):

You miss a comma after u.display_name ... query will be

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, u.user_email, u.user_nicename, u.user_login, u.display_name, 
(
    SELECT  b.date_recorded
    FROM    wp_bp_activity as b
    WHERE   b.type IN ( 'activity_comment','activity_update' )
       AND IF(b.type = 'activity_comment', b.item_id, a.id) = a.id
    ORDER BY b.item_id desc
    limit 0,1
) as drecord
FROM wp_bp_activity as a
LEFT JOIN wp_users as u ON a.user_id = u.ID
WHERE
  a.type IN ( 'activity_update' )
  order by cast(drecord as datetime) desc
 limit 0,20
```

hope this fix the issue... as I didn't check for other errors.

Answer (score 1):

Do you even need the if ?

```
((b.type = 'activity_comment' AND b.item_id = a.id) OR (b.type <> 'activity_comment'))
```

seems to be what you are trying to do

The SQL error like others have said though is the missing comma